# Query to provide key to result mapping on postgres arrays

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table like this

```
multi_id   |      value
------------------------------------
{V1,V2,V3} | PD1
{V4,V5}    | PD2 
{V6,V7}    | PD3
```

Now I want the value where `id = V2` and `V7`. For that I have written a query like

```
select * from some_table where multi_id && ‘{“V2”,“V7"}’;
```

This is giving me result as :

```
multi_id   |      value
------------------------------------
{V1,V2,V3} | PD1
{V6,V7}    | PD3
```

but what I want is:

```
some_column   |      value
------------------------------------
V2            | PD1
V7            | PD3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use unnest:

```
select t.some_column, st.value
from unnest(array['V1','V7']) as t(some_column)
  join some_table st on t.some_column = any(st.multi_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unnest`:

```
select t.id, t.value
from (
    select unnest(multi_id), value
    from table_name tn
) as t(id, value)
where t.id in ('V2', 'V7');
```